# Submitting form a bootstrap form, innerHTML, Alert

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to submit a form which is in bootstrap. Once submission is done (on-click function) I want an alert message which is working fine. But I am unable to go to home page after that. 
Following file opens after that. 
file:///action_page.php?FName=&LName=&email=&pwd=

I am okay to display massage using innerHTML. After that also page is switching to same php file.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("submission").innerHTML = alert("successfully submitted");  
  window.location.href = ".....";
    }
}
</script>

<body>
 <button id="submit" onclick="myFunction()"class="text-light" 
  type="submit">Submit</button>
</body>
```

Comment: What does your form action look like? Can you add the relevant html as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to make an alert, instead of using:

```
document.getElementById("submission").innerHTML = alert("successfully submitted");
```

just use `alert('successfully submitted');`. Alerts aren't shown inside of an HTML, they show on top of your page.

This fixes your problem:

```js
function func() {
  alert("success!");
  window.location = "https://google.com";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="func()">Click me</button>
```

If you're using this button in your form, you will have to override `action` attribute of the form by doing this. Also, if you're using this button to submit a form, use `<input type="submit">` instead.

To override `action` of your form, use `formaction`

W3schools quote:

> The input formaction attribute specifies the URL of the file that will
>   process the input when the form is submitted.
>
> Note: This attribute overrides the action attribute of the 
>   element.

You can combine this with alert so you don't need a separate function:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="alert('success!')" formaction="home.html" value="Click me">

<!-- if you really want, you can also use a button -->

<button type="submit" onclick="alert('success!')" formaction="home.html">Click me</button>
```

[Formaction reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_formaction.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Mamatadb does it fix your problem? If it does, please [mark my reply](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as an answer to your question.